# Assigning Variables from Array in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm fetching table data from a mysql database using PHP. One of the fields in the database (memberProperties) is an array of data that gets outputted like this:

```
{
    "title":"-",
    "first_name":"Joe",
    "last_name":"Bloggs",
    "role":"Senior Scientist",
    "phone":"61240 652135",
    "start_date":"2016-05-20",
    "leave_date":"2016-05-20",
    "location":null,
    "team":"Engineering",
    "platform":"Rockets",   
    "username":"joe.bloggs",
    "from_ad":"true",
    "full_name":"Joe Bloggs",
    "display_name":"Joe Bloggs",
    "mobile":null,
    "company":"ACM WIDGETS"
}
```

**How do I cycle through each value and assign a variable that can be reused in the page?** I have tried to do the following according to a [w3schools PHP tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_list.asp)... but it doesn't seems to output the values separately.

```
$my_array = array($row["memberProperties"]);

      list($title, $first_name, $last_name, $role, $phone, $start_date, $leave_date, $location, $team, $platform, $username, $from_ad, $full_name, $display_name, $mobile, $company) = $my_array;
      echo "$title, $first_name, $last_name, $role, $phone, $start_date, $leave_date, $location, $team, $platform, $username, $from_ad, $full_name, $display_name, $mobile, $company";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As poeple have suggested using json_decode will convert your string to php object

and in your code you can use that like below

```
$memberProperty = json_decode($row["memberProperties"]);

print_r($memberProperty->first_name)
```

the output will be

```
Joe
```

Comment: This answer matches my question on how to cycle through the arrays and output them separately. However it doesn't output the name as suggested. Are you able to check you answer. Any ideas why it might not work?

Comment: i assumed $row["memberProperties"] holding the json list. if so it should give the result

Comment: Yes that is right - but where have you defined $memberProperty?

Answer (score 1):

That's a JSON string. You need to decode it before you can use it as an array. Give this a try:

```
$array = json_decode($row["memberProperties"]);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($array); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
   $string_data = json_decode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value that you have shown within your question is not an instead instead its JSON string you can use `json_decode` along with `foreach` like as

```
$json = '{"title":"-","first_name":"Joe","last_name":"Bloggs","role":"Senior Scientist","phone":"61240 652135","start_date":"2016-05-20","leave_date":"2016-05-20","location":null,"team":"Engineering","platform":"Rockets","username":"joe.bloggs","from_ad":"true","full_name":"Joe Bloggs","display_name":"Joe Bloggs","mobile":null,"company":"ACM WIDGETS"}';

$json_array = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($json_array as $k => $v){
    ${$k} = $v;
}
$arr = get_defined_vars();
print_r($arr);
```

Here `get_defined_vars()` will show you all the variables within your file

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/Hcogs)